# Can Strchr function find numerous letters in a string in c++?

Tags: c++, strchr

```
Diff FBullAndCow::EDifficulty(std::string diff) const
{
    if ((diff.length() > 1))
    {
        return Diff::Not_Number;
    }
    else if (!strchr(diff.c_str(), '3' || '4' || '5' || '6' || '7' || '8'))
    {
        return Diff::Not_Number;
    }
    return Diff::Ok;
}
```

Is it possible to find numerous characters in a string with **strchr**? 
I tried the method above, but it's not working. I suppose it's because **strchr** returns the occurrences of a character?

P.S:. I tried

```
    if ((!strchr(diff.c_str(), '3')) || (!strchr(diff.c_str(), '4')))
```

to use it this way too, though it was probably stupid. I'm a total rookie... I did try to look for a way for hours, but since I couldn't find anything, I'm here.

**EDIT: It needs to return the number it finds. Sorry for leaving this out.**

Comment: Optionally, I can write six different **if** statements, which is working, but that's rather ugly...

Comment: What is `FString`? What is `Diff`? Any reason in particular you skipped `0`, `1`, `2`, and `9`?

Comment: @Barry 
FString is>> using FString = std::string;
and Diff is an enum class. But that doesn't really matter here.
Also, no particular reason why I skipped the rest of the numbers. Just examples.

Comment: Don't use strchr, look at std::string::find_first_of, std::string::find_first_not_of

Comment: @CorpseDead Of course it matters. We know what a `std::string` is an can propose solutions based on that. We don't know what `FString` is.

Comment: Note that `’3’ || ‘4’` etc. has the value 1. `||` is a boolean operator; its result is `false` if both operands are `false` and `true` otherwise.

Comment: If you want to do it in C, the function you’re looking for is `std::strpbrk`: `if (!std::strpbrk(diff.c_str(), “345678”))`. But, as several others have said, you’ve got a `std::string` coming in, and it has member functions to do this test.

Comment: Describe what functionality you are trying to do, for me it looks like there are better ways to tackle this issue. This is called [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer is: no, you cannot check for multiple chars in `strchr`. That function just looks for one, specific character.

If you need to search for all the numeric characters, since you're using a `std::string` (why are you aliasing this?), you can use [`find_first_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of). Or, more likely, [`find_first_not_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of), checking that `diff.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos`.

However, even that's not a good solution - since presumably once you verify that it is numeric, you'll want the actual number. So it may be more direct to just use [`std::stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and verify that it didn't throw and consumed the whole string.

Comment: After checking this function, it seems to do what I need, though I didn't know about it. Thanks a bunch!

Let's say that I need an int input for example from two to nine.
How would I use it in an __if__ statement?

**diff** would be a string and I'd need to check if it is one of the numbers from 2 to 9. I know how to check its length. And the rest is?

I guess I need a variant like:
`std::string num = "23456789";
 if ()
{
    return Diff::Ok; //this is an enum value.
}
`
Let's say I input 5 in the diff variant. How do I test if the input in diff is one of those numbers? @Barry

Comment: @CorpseDead Just convert it to an `int`.